# ListView not responding to click events in Android

Tags: java, android, button, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a custom `ListView` item as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mr_unknown" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture_description"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/real_life_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/FriendListText"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/ping_friend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ping Friend"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

which is used in this ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".FriendListActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/friend_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false"
        style="@style/ListViewStyle" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want that when ever **Ping Friend** button is clicked on any list item it should show an **AlertDialog**. I have used this code...

```
friendListAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(FriendListActivity.this, friends);
friendListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friend_list);
friendListView.setAdapter(friendListAdapter);           

downloadFriends_async(); //This method downloads all the *friends* into ListView from Database. *Its working correctly*.


friendListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Hello!!!");
        alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                FriendListActivity.this.finish();}})
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();}});
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

There is no error shown.

Problem is that its not responding to Click on Button and no AlertDialog appears at all.

For button i also tired adding inside `onItemClick` of **ListView**:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

Button btnPingFriend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ping_friend);
btnPingFriend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

//Rest of AlertDialog Code...

}
```

Still no response.

Please suggest.

Comment: debug your code and add break point add Log and check logcat to varify your route is normal or abnormal

Comment: you able to see the listItems ?

Comment: @RajeshCP yes list view item are getting added successfuly

Comment: put a toast message inside `onItemClick` to make sure that it is getting called

Comment: @RajeshCP New to android... :) Could you please explain bit more?

Comment: Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text);
toast.show();

Comment: Toast.makeText(FriendListActivity.this, "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); add this as the first line inside onIteClick

Comment: @RajeshCP added Toast. No respose. So actually Its not coming inside OnItemClick method. What could be the reason?

Comment: Its actually responding to click on item of list after adding suggestions by @Korniltesav but i want the click to happen on button click and not on complete item. What should i do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the top ViewGroup of your items

**upd**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mr_unknown" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture_description"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/real_life_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/FriendListText"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/ping_friend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ping Friend"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: couldn't get it. Which XML should i add this? <ListView/> or that on the top?

Comment: add that in ur linear layout of List row layout

Comment: @nidhi_adiga It helped. But its launching the Dialogbox on clicking the list item and not on clicking button. What should i do for button click?

Comment: are u sure u have deleted the code posted above, and u set onClickListener on your buttons - not items?

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" - to figure out this one line, I spent almost 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox=new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstActivity.this);


                     alertbox.setTitle("Warning");
                     alertbox.setMessage("Exit Application?");
                     alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new
                     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        /////operations
                     }
                     });
                     alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new
                     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                     }
                     });
                     alertbox.show();

        }
```

Comment: How is this different from OP's first code sample? `AlertDialog.Builder.show()` simply calls `create()` and `show()`, just like OP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to get the `Button` to respond to `onItemClick`, which is used for the `ListView`.

**EDIT:**

In your `getView` method inside your implementation of `ListAdapter` (FriendsListAdapter) you should put this:

```
Button btnPingFriend = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ping_friend);
btnPingFriend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Add your dialog here.
}
```

The `Button` is inside a `ListView` and won't respond to the container's `Listener` - also check out the `Button's` documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html for which `Listeners` you can use...

Comment: But there are lots of button "ping_friend" one with each listitem. So it is not useful to add onclick in oncreate method. should i?

Comment: The `Button` is created for each `ListView` row, so all the `Button's` will respond to the `OnClickListener`. However if you want to know what `ListView` item, the `Button` is in, when you've clicked it you can get the `Button's` parent by calling: `getParent()` and then get the position inside the `ListView` like this: `getListView().getPositionForView((LinearLayout) view.getParent()) - 1;`

Comment: To answer your question: Yes you should ;-)

Comment: If i add OnClick for button inside OnCreate (and removed OnItemClickListener method) its not working and even creates problem loading the FriendsActivity with the list item

Comment: Sorry - I was wrong - the `onClickListener` should be added to the `Button` inside your `getView()` of your implementation of your `ListAdapter` (the `FriendListAdapter`). This way the `onClickListener` is added to every single `Button` for each `ListView` item.